# TypeError: input expected at most 1 arguments, got 3. How to fix this?

Tags: python

```
    n = int(input("type how many input : "))
if n!=0:
    small = int(input("type number 1 value : "))
for i in range(1,n):
    temp = int(input("type number ",n+1," : value "))
    if temp < small:
        small=temp
print (small)
```

I got the following error:

> TypeError: input expected at most 1 arguments, got 3

how can I fix this?

Comment: Don't put `,`  inside the `input` function like that. Use string formatting like `int(input("type number {} : value ".format(n)))`. Either use `str.format` or `f-strings`

Answer (score 1):

You should pay closure attention to the error:

> TypeError: input expected at most 1 arguments, got 3

You passed the `input` function 3 arguments:

1. "type number "
2. n+1
3. " : value "

If you want to pass a complicated string that depend on other variables you should use string formatting like the following:

1. `int(input("type number {} : value ".format(n)))`
2. `int(input("type number %s : value " % n))`

You can read about string formatting in the following link:

https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/